# How do I add animation to a AnimatedList when an Item is re-ordered (changes postion)? [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, animation

[image]

The item needs to lift and animate to the first position when tapped, and then the rest should shift to the right

Tried with AnimatedList and SlideTransition but cant get the item to slide to the first position of the list.

```
AnimatedList(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            key: listKey,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14).w,
            initialItemCount: _categories.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (_, index, animation) => GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                selectedCategory.value = _categories[index];
                final item = _categories.removeAt(index);
                listKey.currentState!.removeItem(index, (context, animation) {
                  return SlideTransition(
                    position: Tween<Offset>(
                      begin: const Offset(0, 0),
                      end: const Offset(-1, 0),
                    ).animate(animation),
                    child: _CourseCategoryItem(
                      title: item,
                      hasDropdown: index == 0,
                    ),
                  );
                });

                listKey.currentState!
                    .insertItem(0, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));
                _categories.insert(0, item);
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: _CourseCategoryItem(
                title: _categories[index],
                hasDropdown: index == 0,
                isSelected: category == _categories[index],
              ),
            ),
          )
```